# Avoiding user interaction with tzdata when installing certbot in a docker container

Tags: apt, docker, automation, letsencrypt

I want to install [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) in a docker environment with an Ubuntu 16.04 image:

For example:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```

When I'm inside the container, the most straightforward way to install certbot does not work as it requires user intervention:

```
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
add-apt-repository -y -u ppa:certbot/certbot && \
apt-get install -y certbot
```

The problem is `tzdata`, which stops with this interactive dialog:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Configuring tzdata
------------------

Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

 1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
 2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
 3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
Geographic area:
```

Strangely enough, it works when I install `tzdata` before adding the ppa:

```
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y tzdata && \
apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
add-apt-repository -y -u ppa:certbot/certbot && \
apt-get install -y certbot
```

**Questions:**

- Why makes it a difference whether I install `tzdata` before or after adding the ppa?
- Is there a better approach for avoiding the interactive dialog when installing certbot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation of a package with parameters being prompted on cli](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365574/installation-of-a-package-with-parameters-being-prompted-on-cli)

Answer (score 363, accepted):

To run `dpkg` (behind other tools like Apt) without interactive dialogue, you can set one environment variable as

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

For example, you can set it in Dockerfile using [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg):

```
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

Comment: Note: `sudo` doesn't pass environment variables through in most cases, so `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get install -y tzdata` works but `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo  apt-get install -y tzdata` doesn't.

Comment: For dockerfiles, add this: ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

Comment: I had a case where this did not work on Ubuntu 18.04. But below answer did fix it on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/a/1098881/112499 as that answer actually fixes the issue instead of hiding it like this one.

Comment: @jerseybean This method is highly discouraged, as explained here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4032

Comment: I thought this was what `-y` was supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 100):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I did that
Dockerfile:

```
ENV TZ=Europe/Minsk
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt update && apt instal....
```

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference for me when I tried US/Denver.  Maybe I have the tz info wrong.

Comment: ["Environment persistence can cause unexpected side effects. To set a value for a single command, use RUN <key>=<value> <command>."](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) You could also try [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg).

Comment: If you can at all avoid it, please use UTC for any code running on a server. See [this (slightly sarcastic) article](http://yellerapp.com/posts/2015-01-12-the-worst-server-setup-you-can-make.html)

Answer (score 85):

**TL&DR:**
Within your DockerFile

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

**Reason:**

Certain Installers make 'installations' easier by having a nice front-end. While this is great when you have a manual install, this becomes an issue during  automated installations.

You can over ride the interactive installation by placing the following in your environment string.

Cheers

Comment: Docker ["best practice is to not use ENV, because that will make the env-var persist in the final image"](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4032#issuecomment-163689851).

Answer (score 29):

You can set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` before your command to avoid `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` affects commands after or child image:

```
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 21):

You should just set your timezone **BEFORE** installing of `tzdata`:

```
# Set timezone:
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$CONTAINER_TIMEZONE /etc/localtime && echo $CONTAINER_TIMEZONE > /etc/timezone

# Install dependencies:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04. Setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` did not!